# Toad for Oracle Formatter

Tags: toad

How can one change the code formater in Toad for things not in the options list?

**my example**

I want Toad to format my `with` statements so that they are easy to debug:

```sql
WITH 
  a AS (
    SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
       )
, b AS (
      SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
       )
SELECT a.*, b.* from a,b
```

But toad formats it like this

```sql
WITH a AS (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),
     b AS (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM a, b
```

where this becomes useful is with bigger with statements where you may want to run "A" and "B" but nothing after that,  you would be able to comment out the line

```sql
--, b AS (
```

and highlight the code you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your toad formatter in

View -> Toad Options -> Formatter

You can configure to breakline before ',' as you wanted